# Android multi Screen Support

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I know that for supporting different screen size we use layout,layout-large,layout-xlarge folder , but i have confusion regarding drawable folder,by default they are  ,

```
1. drawable-ldpi For low density screens
2. drawable-mdpi For medium density screens
3. drawable-hdpi For high resolution screens
4. drawable-xhdpi For extra high resolution screens

   But A simple approch is 


   1.Drawable
   2.Drawable-large 
   3.Drawable-xlarge
```

is it ok to go with this approch?

Answer (score 0):

Google changed layout system after API 13 (Android 3) so both of them works but it's recommended to use dpi system which related to screen density but old system was realted to screen sizes which might make problems with large screen devices with low dpi screen density

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use screen density folders because ([quoting the Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence))

> Maintaining density independence is important because, without it, a UI element
>   (such as a button) appears physically larger on a low density screen and smaller
>   on a high density screen. Such density-related size changes can cause problems in
>   your application layout and usability.

So using density-pixels Android scales your widgets (Buttons, ImageViews, etc) by itself relating your **Activity** and the **Drawables** you need to the appropiate res folder. In fact, you should be using this density system in your **Layouts** too (layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, etc).